# How to create chm file using the directory containing html files

Tags: chm, html-help, html-help-workshop

I have a directory containing multiple html files. Need to create chm file using all the html files of the directory.

I am trying to create chm file using chmprocessor.

(downloaded from- http://sourceforge.net/projects/chmprocessor/files/)

I have referred http://chmprocessor.sourceforge.net/ and tried following:

I selected html file using "Add file" under Source Files tab. And selected the directory using "Add directory" under additional files tab. But it didn't worked.

Could any one please suggest the steps to create chm file using the directory containing html files?

I have also tried using HTML Help Workshop, but this tool does not provide the capability to directly create chm file by selecting the directory containing html files.

Answer (score 2):

This is really annoying - after installing chmProcessor I have given the tool a longer try and the chmProcessor for (good structered) Word files (*.doc) is really working good.

But testing for HTML with the one selected HTML at 'Source files' makes me crazy as a former Microsoft Help MVP. Only linked files are included in the CHM I added with "Add Directory".

I put a 'Change Request' for more documentation about 'Source files' to SourceForge where you may download my test sample and some snaps of things I tried:
http://sourceforge.net/p/chmprocessor/bugs/29/

HTMLHelp Workshop has a learn curve and creating Table of Contents (TOC) needs a fairly long time.

So, one more thought: You may have your HTML files in a web structure with sub-directories. A tool I have experience with is FAR HTML. Using the Help Wizard makes a CHM in some minutes. These is shown in a Video I uploaded for you. Give it a try - it's free with full working functions for some weeks.
http://www.help-info.de/files_share/VideoCreateChmHelpFilesWithFAR-HTML.mp4